# truffle.ps1 cannot be loaded

Tags: npm, truffle

> ```
> PS F:\projects\fund-project> truffle init
> truffle : File C:\Users\Hari\AppData\Roaming\npm\truffle.ps1 cannot be loaded because running 
> At line:1 char:1
> + truffle init
> + ~~~~~~~
>    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
> ```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this link can help you
Although this command is used for angular not truffle.
But, you need to change some security config in power shell admin.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-fix-ps1-can-not-be-loaded-because-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-sys/

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/126114/i-have-problem-installing-truffle-when-i-try-npm-truffle-v-i-get-this-error-me   for   Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser    RemoteSigned
 LocalMachine    Unrestricted

Answer (score 0):

after those changes I got

PS C:\Users\homa\workspace\firstPro> truffle init

## Starting init...

> Copying project files to C:\Users\homas\workspace\firstPro

Init successful, sweet!

Try our scaffold commands to get started:
$ truffle create contract YourContractName # scaffold a contract
$ truffle create test YourTestName         # scaffold a test

http://trufflesuite.com/docs
in powershell